# Python, get an error when using np.dstack and can’t solve it

Tags: python, numpy, collections, scikit-image, imread

When running the following code

```
mport matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage, skimage.io
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
from skimage import io

ic = skimage.io.imread_collection('/Users/ /remoteSensing/Image/Landsat/*.tif') 
img = np.dstack((ic[5],ic[4],ic[3]))
```

I got the following error.
TypeError: unexpected keyword argument: img_num

I read in an old question that there was a bug in the older version of NumPy and scikit-image but my versions are
numpy                         1.19.1
scikit-image                  0.17.2
tifffile                      0.15.1

I would appreciate any help to solve this error.

here is the link of the folder /Landsat
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AizvpupSaqfjhzcdFz173WMZfo_J?e=N1UaeL

this is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ee45cc9a6663> in <module>
----> 1 img = np.dstack((ic[5],ic[4],ic[3]))
      2 

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/io/collection.py in __getitem__(self, n)
    274                         kwargs['img_num'] = img_num
    275                     try:
--> 276                         self.data[idx] = self.load_func(fname, **kwargs)
    277                     # Account for functions that do not accept an img_num kwarg
    278                     except TypeError as e:

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/imageio_plugin.py in imread(*args, **kwargs)
      8 @wraps(imageio_imread)
      9 def imread(*args, **kwargs):
---> 10     return np.asarray(imageio_imread(*args, **kwargs))

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py in imread(uri, format, **kwargs)
    263 
    264     # Get reader and read first
--> 265     reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)
    266     with reader:
    267         return reader.get_data(0)

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py in get_reader(uri, format, mode, **kwargs)
    184 
    185     # Return its reader object
--> 186     return format.get_reader(request)
    187 
    188 

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imageio/core/format.py in get_reader(self, request)
    168                 "Format %s cannot read in %s mode" % (self.name, modename)
    169             )
--> 170         return self.Reader(self, request)
    171 
    172     def get_writer(self, request):

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imageio/core/format.py in __init__(self, format, request)
    219             self._request = request
    220             # Open the reader/writer
--> 221             self._open(**self.request.kwargs.copy())
    222 
    223         @property

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imageio/plugins/tifffile.py in _open(self, **kwargs)
    224                 self._f = None
    225                 f = self.request.get_file()
--> 226             self._tf = _tifffile.TiffFile(f, **kwargs)
    227 
    228             # metadata is the same for all images

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in __init__(self, arg, name, offset, size, multifile, _useframes, _master, **kwargs)
   2461                         setattr(self, key, bool(value))
   2462                 else:
-> 2463                     raise TypeError(f'unexpected keyword argument: {key}')
   2464 
   2465         fh = FileHandle(arg, mode='rb', name=name, offset=offset, size=size)

TypeError: unexpected keyword argument: img_num
```

Comment: Reread the docs for `dstack`.  Pay attention to the number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try updating your scikit-image version and installing tifffile as well? scikit-image 0.17 changed the way tiff files are read and that might fix the problem.

Additionally, as pointed out by hpaulj, you need to pass in a list/tuple to `np.dstack`:

`np.dstack((ic[5], ic[4], ic[3]))`

(note the extra set of parentheses.)

**Update**

We finally figured this out [on the skimage issue tracker](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4979). The fix is to specify the tifffile plugin when calling `imread_collection`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage, skimage.io
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
from skimage import io

ic = skimage.io.imread_collection(
    '/Users/ /remoteSensing/Image/Landsat/*.tif', plugin='tifffile'
) 
img = np.dstack((ic[5],ic[4],ic[3]))
```

Comment: thank you. I did add another set of parentheses but still getting error. Is there any newer version of scikit-image?

Comment: Which version do you have now?

Comment: my current version  is scikit-image 0.17.2  I get error wherever I need to open an image collection

Comment: and your tifffile version?

Comment: Also, could you update the question to reflect the current version and the corresponding traceback? I think it is probably different. Finally, if you could provide a zip file of an example failing folder, that would be really useful to be able to reproduce the error locally. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-post

Comment: I did update and put a link(hope it works) thank you

Comment: Great, thanks, can you update your version of tifffile? The current version is 2020.8.25 (https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/). It looks like scikit-image is using the imageio plugin rather than the tifffile plugin directly, which means it is not finding (or maybe is not compatible with) the installed tifffile version.

Comment: yes, the tiffile version is 2020.8.25 now.though the error is still the same. ''' conda list''' gives me this; [tifffile                  2020.8.25                  py_0    conda-forge]

Comment: It's very strange that it would prefer imageio to tifffile for this. Can you try adding `plugin='tifffile'` to your call to `imread_collection`?